# With FAKE, is there a way to get the entire build log?

Tags: f#, build-process, f#-fake

Is there a way to get all of the build messages with FAKE so at the end of a build I can email the build log?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is run FAKE with the extra command line argument

```
--log filename
```

All output will be logged to that file during the build.

Comment: If I run `Fake.exe build.fsx --logfile build.log` from cmd, the log file gets written correctly. If I run `Fake.exe build.fsx fooParam=bar --logfile build.log`, it does not work. Do you know how to pass parameters to the build script and parameters to Fake?

Comment: @NexAddo I think you're supposed to use `--fsiargs` before the parameters.  If you do that you need to include the name of the script as an argument too.  This is the page you need to look at for more details: http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/commandline.html